# How to create testcase for a class which contains enum references & parameterized constructors?

Tags: java

I have a class A which contains enum reference variables and parameterized constructors.Now i need to create a testcase for class A. how can i create objects for that enum reference variables of class A in class TestA?

Example:

```
class A{    
private Enum1 enum1;   
private Enum2 enum2;   
private Enum3 enum3;   
private Enum4 enum4;    
private Enum5 enum5;    

public A(Enum1 enum1,Enum2 enum2){    }    

public A(Enum1 enum1,Enum2 enum2,Enum3 enum3){      ......    ......    }
```

Comment: I don't understand the Q. If you have, say, `public enum EnumOne { UNO, DUE, TRES}` then something like `EnumOne.DUE` is all you need to write. The "creation" happens for all the enum objects when the enum class is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your constructors do something like this :-

```
public A(Enum1 enum1,Enum2 enum2,...){  

this.enum1=enum1;
this.enum2=enum2;
.
.
.

  }
```

Its really simple, Create Enum objects and pass them to the constructor of class A , like this:-

```
class TestA(){

public static void main(String args[]){

Enum1 e1=Enum1.Enum1Value1;
Enum2 e2=Enum2.Enum2Value1;

A a=new A(e1,e2);

Enum1 en1=Enum1.Enum1Value2;
Enum2 en2=Enum2.Enum2Value2;
Enum3 en2=Enum3.Enum3Value2;

A b=new A(en1,en2,en3);
.
.
.
.
.

}
}
```

Comment: Why the complication with the additional variables? `new A(Enum1.Enum1Value2,...)` is sufficient.

Comment: This one is ok.One more Q, I have a generic type of enum ref variable.how to create object for that generic type of ref variable in testcase class? for ex: class abc<T>{ Enum1 enum1; Enum2 enum2; T payload; ....} how can i create object for that 'payload' of generic type

Comment: First of all please follow naming conventions in java, class names should start with capital letter, anyways You can do something like this in your Test class's method, `abc<Integer> a1=new abc<Integer>(); a1.payload=new Integer(10); ` . This replaces the placeholder T with Integer type ,When creating objects of that class.

Answer (score 0):

If you have, say,

```
public enum EnumOne {
   UNO, DUE, TRES
}
```

the objects `UNO`,... are created when the enum class is loaded. So there is no need for extra work.

For tests then something like `EnumOne.DUE` is all you need to write.